# Device width based on media queries on css

Tags: css, media-queries

I have written media queries for my latest project and everything just works perfect except for when the screen width is less than 300px , while viewing with the help of emulator on chrome. I want to know if there is any device whose screen is less than 300px. Any answer will be highly appreciated

Thanks beforehand

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily worry about this, most devices report a minimum viewport width of 320px. I can't even think of exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are devices out there with < 300px wide screen resolution (e.g, the Omate smart watch, HTC Tattoo), but that probably isn't what you need to worry about. Instead, you could use some page analytic software (e.g, Google Analytics, AWStats) and determine, "What resolutions do my users have?"

Trying to make your site work with < 300 px just because a device exists sounds like a lot of work for a niche use case that will probably never run into.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, be sure to click the "checkmark" icon to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted", thanks!